# flat memory model vs. real-address mode memory model

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, intel

From *Intel IA32 Software Developer's Manual*,

```
Flat memory model — Memory appears to a program as a single, continuous address  
space. This space is called a linear address space. Code, data, and stacks are  
all contained in this address space. Linear address space is byte addressable,  
with addresses running contiguously from 0 to 2^32 - 1 (if not in 64-bit mode).  
An address for any byte in linear address space is called a linear address.

Real-address mode memory model — This is the memory model for the Intel 8086  
processor. It is supported to provide compatibility with existing programs  
written to run on the Intel 8086 processor. The realaddress mode uses a specific  
implementation of segmented memory in which the linear address space for the  
program and the operating system/executive consists of an array of segments of up  
to 64 KBytes in size each. The maximum size of the linear address space in  
real-address mode is 220 bytes.
```

According to the information above, is The difference between these two memory models just addressable memory space size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real-address mode also uses segments.

The flat memory model is the intuitive, straightforward  memory model used by most processors (not from Intel). Most processors do not support multiple memory models. Intel supports this plus many others for compatibility.

Real-address mode uses segment registers. An addresses is the value specified by the programmer plus the value in a segment register, In some cases, the segment may be implicit from the particular instruction.

Comment: Can I consider **flat memory model** as a giant-size address space without segments version of the **real-address mode memory model**?

Comment: I wouldn't call flat memory model as a version of real address mode. It's the plain vanilla memory model. Real mode is a hack to allow a 16-bit processor to access more memory than 64K. (Just think how much farther the industry would be if IBM had adopted the 68000 rather than the 8086).

Comment: In **flat momory model**, code, data and stack are in the same memory range (normally 0~4GB), the application program should itself manage it's code, data and stack to prevent a mess. Am I correct?